# Can ForEach() use the parent of a SelectMany()?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a parent class, call it Parent, that contains a List, call this Children. I want to take a List and set a property from the parent on each of the Children. I can do this, which works fine:

```
foreach( Parent parent in Parents )
{
    foreach( Child child in parent.Children )
    {
        child.Description = parent.Name;
    }
}
```

But I wonder if there's some terser Linq ForEach syntax that would work for this, something like (this doesn't work, but it seems like it should):

```
parents.SelectMany( parent => parent.Children ).ToList().ForEach( child => child.Description = parent.Name );
```

This fails even if I omit the ToList() and use the MoreLinq library, which permits a ForEach directly on an enumerable. Am I missing something or should I just resign myself to the double loop?

Comment: What's wrong with your original code anyways? It's perfectly readable.

Comment: You'd need to include the parent in the `SelectMany` like `p => p.Children.Select(c => new { Parent = p, Child = c})` but Linq isn't really meant for mutating and creating an intermediate list just to use `ForEach` is an abomination IMHO.

Comment: Linq the Q stands for query.  Your for loop isn't a query.  You are adding data to an existing object.  You need the for loops when inserting into an existing object.  This code is a query : var results = Parents.SelectMany(parent => parent.Where(child => child.Description = parent.Name).Select(x => new {parent = parent, child = child}));

Comment: You all seem to be telling me that the best way to write this is as it is already written, and on reflection I agree with you. Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 2):

You could use ConvertAll which will update your child list:

```
parents.ForEach(x => x.Children.ToList().ConvertAll(y => y.Description = x.Name));
```

[Example dotNetFiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9iQoNy)